# Pressing Ctrl+Z while editing tags in Firefox deletes the whole tag

Tags: bug, tags, editor, firefox

I noticed something weird happening while editing tags on a question:

1. Initial state:

   > [image: Screenshot #1]
2. After pressing the **backspace key** once, to edit the last tag:

   > [image: Screenshot #2]
3. After pressing **undo** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>):

   > [image: Screenshot #3]

I would've expected the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to either do nothing (since I haven't actually edited the tag name yet) or to take me back to state 1.  Instead, it **deletes the whole tag**!  Surely that's not reasonable UI behavior?

Comment: +1, I can reproduce this on Firefox 27 / Linux: pressing Ctrl+Z *immediately* after starting to edit an existing tag deletes the whole tag. If you make some changes to the tag name first, the first Ctrl+Z undoes those changes (as expected), but pressing it again still deletes the tag.

Comment: no repro in the inline tag editor.

Comment: @Undo: I *can* repro this also in the inline tag editor on Firefox. Doesn't happen on Chromium, though.

Comment: Reproduced in the inline *post* editor (not the *edit tags* button).